# Angular.js routing: how do I reach endpoint routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, url-routing

After trying all I can imagine, and reading several posts here, I think I need your help!
I have a webapp based on node and express on the server and Angular on the client. I am using angular routing.

BASIC INFO

I have the routing set up like the following:

```
mainApp.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'initial.ejs',
                controller: 'controllerInitialView'
            })
            .when('/home/post', {
                templateUrl: 'post.ejs',
                controller: 'controllerAddPost'
            })
            .... other /home/something routes ..
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'
            });
            }
           ]);
```

The html template is organized as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
      <!-- Left Columns: With links to views -->
      <div class="col-xs-2 home-bd-dx">
       <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/home/post"> Post </a>
        </li>
        ...
        <li>
          <a href="/logout"> Logout </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </div>

    <!-- Central Columns: Here the views are inserted -->
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
```

The issue is with the Logout link. I have a server `serverapp.get('/logout')` link which uses passport.js to logout the user. However, I cannot manage to reach that link. Whatever I try transforms my `/logout`, into `/home/logout`, and it is handled by Angular rather than by the server.

QUESTION

So here is the question: *how can I create links to endpoint routes in Angular without Angular router intercepting them?*

ADDITIONAL INFO IF NEEDED

The express server is has a route `serverapp.get('/home/*')` which delegates these routes to Angular.js by returning the template I sketched above.

I tried with and without a `<base href="/home">` tag in the `<head>` with no luck

I tried creating a route '/home/logout', and then having the angular `$window.location.href="/logout";` in the controller of `/home/logout`. No luck also in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you're trying to do is disabling deep linking for certain URLs. You can do that by adding `target="_self"` to the `<a>` tag.

Try this:

```
<a href="/logout" target="_self">Logout</a>
```

Now the URL the link is pointing to will be handled by the server instead of Angular.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but I do not understand why this skips angular routing. From the [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) I read the following about `_self`:"Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)". If by frame it means window or tab, it says where the link is opened, so I do not get what this has to do with routing. Furthermore, it specifies that this is the default behavior. From here I understand that `<a>` without `target=...` is equivalent to having `target=_self`, under which circumstances Angular routing is not skipped.